# What if computer get full when synchronizing with Google Drive

Tags: hard-drive, sync, google-drive

As said in Google Drive Help page, "your device can sync with Google Drive on the web so that you can view your files from any device. https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374992" If my files on Google Drive are large enough to make my disk full, what's gonna happen? Can it still sync?

Put it in another way: can sync with Google Drive app make my computer's disk full?